# unpivot null becomes empty string SQL Server 2014

Tags: sql, sql-server, unpivot

I am using SQL Server 2014 RTM Developer Edition. I am using my query in SSMS and not in SSIS. I have so many NULL values in table that I use in my UNPIVOT function.And after Unpivot, I dont see those rows become columns because of NULLs.If I use @NULL then I see all data properly.

So I found some hotfix from microsoft for SSIS (not for SSMS problem). 
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3058512
Instead of applying that hotfix, I installed SQL 2014 SP2 and restarted machine.
No difference.

Then I installed Cumulative update 1 for SQL Server 2014 SP2 and still same thing. Why is this happening?

```
DECLARE @colsUnpivot NVARCHAR(MAX)
       ,@query  VARCHAR(MAX)
       ,@Table_name  NVarchar(500)
       ,@fiscal_year Varchar(4) 

      SET @Table_name = 'opd_scholar'
      SET @fiscal_year = '2015'

       set @colsUnPivot = STUFF((SELECT ',' + QUOTENAME(code_name) from  opd_lkp_scholar t Where fiscal_year = 2015 AND code_name NOT IN    ('UNITID','Institution','City','State','Zip') FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE          ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') ,1,1,'') 
       PRINT @colsUnPivot

        set @query 
        = ' INSERT INTO opd_scholar_transaction (    unitid,institution,city,state,zip,code_name,lkp_value) 
    SELECT unitid,institution,city,state,zip,code_name,lkp_value
     FROM  
     (
      SELECT unitid,institution,city,state,zip, '+ @colsUnpivot+'
        FROM '+@Table_name+') AS cp
         UNPIVOT (lkp_value for code_name  IN ('+@colsUnPivot+')
         ) AS up'
       PRINT @Query
           exec(@query)
```

In my opd_Scholar table I have 400 columns and I need them to convert as rows.
And I have so many NULL values in opd_scholar table. But when I use above code to convert these rows to columns its not showing those values that has NULLs.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you are asking for. But try `isnull(YOURVALUE,'')`

Comment: Thanks furin but this will replace nu,lls to empty strings?? I prefer NULL as NULL.

Comment: Even if I go for ur suggestion, I am pulling column names dynamically  so How do I check this for each and every column values??

Comment: Okay so I figured this but now new issue,

Answer (score 1):

Thanks, I found NULL to 0 solution but

```
    set @colsUnPivot = STUFF((SELECT ',' +  'ISNULL(' + QUOTENAME(code_name) + ', 0) AS ' + QUOTENAME(code_name) from opd_lkp_scholar t Where fiscal_year = 2015 AND code_name NOT IN ('UNITID','Institution','City','State','Zip') FOR XML                    PATH(''), TYPE ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') ,1,1,'') 
   PRINT @colsUnPivot
```

But I have more than 400 columns and @query is varchar(max) still they all dont fir into that. How do I split this??